# How to control child windows size+position of Windows 10 UWP App

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-store-apps, childwindow

How to enumerate and control the position and size
of child windows of ApplicationFrameHost.exe
from Powershell.... or C#

In this case the Windows of Microsoft.Notes (Sticky Notes)
(This App uses Metro/UWP GUI components like Edge, Calculator, etc.)

In this case only the open notes...
(open Microsoft.Notes Windows)

But I am curious also iif the Note/Window Position+Size
can be saved within the note

Comment: How do you make child windows? Do you use AppWindow  class?

Comment: I want to control the windows of an existing app (MS Sticky Notes)... they are under ApplicationFrameHost.exe

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no such api that could not control Sticky Notes app window position within UWP platform.